# Googlebot no indexa página generada generada desde default.aspx

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, google-search

Desde la página default.aspx genero dinámicante páginas para que el motor de Google las indexe y las encuentre.

Las páginas indexadas tienen este formato

```
<a  href='../detalleArticulo.aspx?id=1'></a>
<a  href='../detalleArticulo.aspx?id=1'></a>
```

Y así sucesivamente.

En la página detalleArticulo.aspx genero dinámicamente:

```
document.title = "la descripcion del producto"
```

Y la veo así en el titulo, pero las páginas igual NO son indexadas por el motor de Google

Estoy trabajando con Visual 2019, c# y con MasterPage.

¿Alguna idea de como hacer para que el motor de Google me indexe la página detalleArticulo.aspx con distintos "id"?

Saludos y agradezco cualquier ayuda